# Does $(p\implies q)\implies\neg( q\implies p)$?

Tags: logic, soft-question, terminology

$p\implies q$ does not necessarily indicate that $q\implies p$, which is why there exists a double-sided implication: $\iff$.

$p\iff q$ is the same as saying $(p\implies q)\land(q\implies p)$. However, sometimes when I am illustrating my working out, I use the one-sided $\implies$ symbol even when using the $\iff$ symbol would also work. My question is: does $p\implies q$ directly say that $q\implies p$ is false? Even if it does not, is it better practice to try and always use $\iff$ when it works both ways?

Comment: No. Check it with truth table.

Comment: Writing $p\implies q$ doesn't imply that the converse is false. It's often useful to notice when your logical steps are reversible (i.e. when things are equivalences instead of just implications) but it's not required. Sometimes one direction is a lot easier than the other.

Comment: Is it possible that your posted question has a typo?  Is it possible that you intended $~(p \implies q) \implies ( ~[\neg q] \implies [\neg p] ~) ~?$

Comment: "does p⟹q directly say that q⟹p is false?"  Of course not.  " is it better practice to try and always use ⟺ when it works both ways?"  It's better practice to not say things that aren't important.  If whether $q\implies p$ is completely irrelevant, why talk about it? Penguins eat fish is always true but I usually don't include it in my mathematical proofs.

Answer (score 1):

By definition: $(p\Longrightarrow q)\equiv(q\lor\lnot p)$ and $\lnot(q\Longrightarrow p)\equiv(q\land\lnot p)$. Clearly if $q$ holds and $p$ holds or if $\lnot q$ and $\lnot p$ hold, your implication fails.

Edit: The notation $p\Longleftrightarrow q$ is just a short form for $(p\Longrightarrow q)\land(q\Longrightarrow p)$. When using only a one-sided arrow, one doesn't say anything about the converse direction. It can be used when one doesn't really care about the converse direction.